Azure Durable Function - Change the default port for Azurite
I have created a .NET 8 isolated worker durable orch function using C#. I am unable to run the solution in my local as I am having issues while trying to turn on Azurite in my local.
I get this error:
myTestProj: Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
myTestProj: Azurite Blob service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10000
myTestProj: Azurite Queue service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10001
myTestProj: Exit due to unhandled error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:10001

How do I change the default port of Azurite? The official documentation of MS about Azurite doesn't help.
I am getting this error when i am trying to run the commands mentioned in above MS link. I have tried in both command prompt and Microsoft Azure command prompt.

'azurite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any help here will be greatly helpful.

My local settings file for now: {
"IsEncrypted": false,
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
}
}. I know this needs to be changed further as the default port is getting changed.


'azurite' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Any help here will be greatly helpful.

This error occurs when the azurite is not installed and i have faced similar issue , To install it use npm install -g azurite in cmd prompt and followed MS-Doc:

Now it got installed.
I got similar error as you have:

Checked the ports, and they are already in use:
netstat -ano | findstr :10000 and 10002:

So, firstly killed them:
taskkill /PID 24160 /F


Then when typed azurite, it worked successfully:


Change the default port for Azurite

To change port, you can use azurite --blobPort 10006 --queuePort 10007.
